# Storing data in a map of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I'm trying to create a database. I want to store names and ID's along with course information and grades. For each ID there needs to be multiple courses stored. To do this I'm thinking of using a map of vectors. Assigning an ID to use as a key for the map and then the vector to store the course information etc. I have all in a class inheritance system that goes Abstract Base Class>Student>Degree (includes course info etc). Is this the best way of doing this seeing as I can't dynamically create class instances?

Edit:
Say I have a class foo, and want to create new instances of it.

`` X=1

"Would you like to add a new user?: y"

foo newuserX

"Would you like to add another user?: y"

foo newuserX++

......

`foo newuserX++ ``

Comment: 1. A degree is not a student, this hierarchy makes no sense. 2. What do you mean by "dynamically create class instances" and what kind of problem do you have doing it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to store?  Names, IDs (IDs of what)?  "Course Information and grades" -- separately?  You should try to normalize your data first, then see what you need to effectively store it.

Comment: @n.m.: He's not saying a Student is a Degree. He's saying that there would be a class called Degree which contained a vector of all of the classes the student has taken. The Degree class would be a member of the Student class.

Comment: @n.m A student will be taking a degree, maths for example, the degree class inherits the information from the student class. So we have their name, ID etc, along with their degree information. By dynamically creating class instances I mean I want to create multiple Students, each having course information stored within the degree class. I can't work out how to do this on the fly.

Comment: @Chad I would like to store Names and ID's in the Student class, then course information in the degree class.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What if a student takes two degrees? Or drops a degree? A degree is **associated** with a student. As for the second question I do not understand where the difficulty lies. Can you show some pseudocode that you cannot turn into real code?

Comment: @0A0D I have a hard time correlating the string "Abstract Base Class>Student>Degree" with your interpretation. Things called "Abstract Base Class" usualluy start unheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @n.m. Then you have a vector of Degrees and in that Degree class is a set of course information.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Start by modeling all of your data types.  `Student`, attributes such as ID, name, etc.  `Course`, attributes such as ID, name, etc.  `Degree` -- ID, name, collection of required courses.  Then from those base types build up the relationships you need to model, a `Student` takes courses and gets a grade, and so on.

Comment: @n.m. I read that you can't dynamically create new class instances in C++?
I'd like to do something like

`class foo`  

`{`  

  `.....`  

   `"Enter a new student? (y or n): y "`  
   `foo newX`  
   `"Another? y"`  
   `foo newX+1`  

If that makes sense? [Apologies for the formatting, attempting to improve it]

Comment: Update your question, don't put this stuff in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but this doesn't look like (pseudo)code **at all**. I'm going to downvote and vote to close this, "not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here."

Comment: @n.m. Is that code any better? It is a real question. It's a question on if I can create new instances of my class depending on user input.

Comment: Oh of course you can. It's the most basic of most basic things. I suggest you pick up a coherent text on C++ and start learning the language. "Accelerated C++" by Koenig and Moo is much recommended.

Comment: Got there in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a multimap to store multiple values for a key, and then iterator over the values when looking for the courses corresponding to a ID.

Comment: I'd like to do it so that I don't have to input the name of the student each time. So that there is a multimap just in the degree class. Sorry I'm not the best at explaining this more clearly. I mean a Student class instance (I hope this is the correct terminology) has a degree instance which inherits the name etc, which contains this multimap. But I can't work out how to create these student class instances without knowing a predetermined number of students are going to be inputted.